# Writing and then removing node from XML doc using C#/Unity3D

Tags: c#, .net, xml, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add nodes to an xml document and then deleting them.
Adding nodes is working, but i cant remove nodes unless i restart the program.

The Write method:

```
public void writeToExistingDoc (String fileNamePath, int x, int y, int t)
{
    string filename = fileNamePath;
    string xPos = "" + x;
    string yPos = "" + y;
    string type = "" + t;

    //create new instance of XmlDocument
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument ();

    //load from file
    doc.Load (filename);

    //create node and add value
    XmlNode node = doc.CreateNode (XmlNodeType.Element, "BUILDING", null);

    XmlAttribute atr = doc.CreateAttribute ("x");
    XmlAttribute atr2 = doc.CreateAttribute ("y");
    XmlAttribute atr3 = doc.CreateAttribute ("type");
    atr.Value = xPos;
    atr2.Value = yPos;
    atr3.Value = type;
    node.Attributes.Append (atr);
    node.Attributes.Append (atr2);
    node.Attributes.Append (atr3);



    //add to elements collection
    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild (node);

    Debug.Log ("Element added");
    //save back
    doc.Save (filename);

}
```

and here is the Remove method:

```
public void removeBuildingNode (string fileNamePath, int buildingPosX, int buildingPosY)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument ();
    doc.Load (fileNamePath);
    XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes ("//BUILDING[@x='" + buildingPosX + "']");
    for (int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Debug.Log("" + i);
        nodes[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild (nodes[i]);
    }
    doc.Save(fileNamePath);
    Debug.Log(""+buildingPosX + ", " + buildingPosY);


}
```

My XML doc looks like this:

```
<BUILDINGS ID="b">
<BUILDING x="50" y="80" type="1" />
<BUILDING x="25" y="125" type="1" />
<BUILDING x="35" y="125" type="1" />
<BUILDING x="45" y="125" type="1" />
</BUILDINGS>
```

As i've said, the methods work when i first run the program, use the write method, the restart the program and use the remove method. Wont work on the same running instance.

Comment: btw, im only using the x-coordinates for now.

Comment: What goes wrong? If I use your code and test doc to add then remove the same node one after the other it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't bent on using XmlDocument, this should work...

Using: http://searisen.com/xmllib/extensions.wiki

```
public void removeBuildingNode (string fileNamePath, int buildingPosX, int buildingPosY)
{
    XElement doc = XElement.Load(fileNamePath);
    var nodesToRemove = doc.Elements("BUILDING")
        .Where(xe => xe.Get("x", int.MinValue) == buildingPosX);

    foreach(XElement node in nodesToRemove.ToArray())
         node.Remove();

    doc.Save(fileNamePath);

    Debug.Log(""+buildingPosX + ", " + buildingPosY);
}
```

Comment: having trouble using the .Where() method and the "from" keyword. Ive added the libraries and the extention.

Comment: should be `in` instead of `from` - my mistake.  The `Where` compiles just fine for me.  You did put a `using XmlLib;` at the top of the file with your other usings or changed the namespace to be the same as your file?  You can't snip out the Get() method and put it in the same class.  Extension methods must be in a static class.